# Ip address connot be converted to host name in apache

Tags: apache

I am trying to configure and host my static html page  on apache2 webserver.

But it is not converting the ip address to the host name.

This is my configuration in var/www/default file

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName gameplayer.com
    ServerAlias www.gameplayer.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/gameplayer
    CustomLog /var/www/logs/gameplayer.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/www/logs/gameplayer.log
<VirtualHost>
```

When I trying to load it is showing no page found error.

When I am calling it by ip add-192.*.*.* it showing a list of websites.
and when I click one of them my path of that website is

```
    192.*.*.*/websitename.
```

Instead this I want to load the website without prefix of ip address.

As I am a learner I don't know where is the problem? please help me.

And please can anybody tell me how to host two different websites on same web server on two different ports?

**[Edit]**

```
Listen 8999

NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8999


<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8999>
    ServerName gameplayer.com
    ServerAlias www.gameplayer.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/gameplayer-8999
    CustomLog /var/www/logs/gameplayer.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/www/logs/gameplayer.log
<VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Is `www.gameplayer.com` pointing to your server? Has port 80 been opened in the server's firewall? Is Apache listening on port 80? Have you restarted Apache after changing the configuration file?

Comment: Does the hostname exist in DNS? or in your local hosts file?   I am assuming you don't own gameplayer.com, as it was registered in 1997 and held by a squatter..  In order to get name resolution working using http hosts headers (What you are doing). The computer you are accessing it from needs to be able to resolve the name to an IP address.  So either add the name to DNS, or create a host entry in your hosts files.  (Also this is probably better asked at superuser, maybe serverfault)

Comment: @Pekka웃: how can I check that apache is listening port 80 or not?

Comment: It should say "listen 80" somewhere in the server config file; to see whether it's actually working see e.g. http://www.pc-freak.net/blog/linux-check-apache-server-listening-port-80-443/

Comment: the fact that you can browse it by IP address and you get the directory index of presumably /var/www  pretty sure that it is listening on port 80 nad that it isn't firewalled (at least locally)

Comment: @Doon : no I am not the owner of this hostname and I dont know that it is registered name.

Comment: @Pekka웃 : yes it is listening..What should I do in such case?

Comment: You need to own the domain first, of course. Do you have one? Or do you just want a local web site, in your network?

Comment: as @Pekka웃 said, what is the end goal.   If you are using name based virtual hosting you need to have a valid name configured that your endusers (be it local or $world) can resolve.  So this normally means adding the name to DNS (or each computers hosts file) so when enduser types in http://my.domain.com/ they get back 192.x.x.x. So when they make an HTTP request to 192.x.x.x.  and send header, `HOST: my.domain.com`  Apache looks at that hostname, looks at the config and says here give them this content...

Comment: @Pekka웃: No I just want to try it locally as per learning purpose..!!

Comment: @Doon : can you tell me how to run on localhost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to run / test on localhost (Pulling from comments)

You will need to edit your hosts file. On *nix operating systems, this file is normally located at  `/etc/hosts`, on Windows Systems it is normally `c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`

you need to follow the format of the file and add something like this.

```
192.x.x.x   gameplayer.com www.gameplayer.com
```

or if you are doing it on localhost, replace `192.x.x.x.`  with `127.0.0.1` (or `::1` if using ipv6 -- or just add the hostnames to the existing entries for localhost)

Comment: I have updated my code please check it. still Its not working after making changes as you said. Is there anything that should I do?

I am doing it on localhost so I did not change my host file

Comment: What do you mean you made changes as I said, but didn't change my hostfile?  you need to change your host file there is no way around that (short of creating proper dns entries).  What is happening is that you are asking your browser  to go to htp://gameplayer.com/  , it looks up that entry in dns (Which doesn't exist) so the browser  gets an error.. You need to make sure that the whatever name you used with `servername` can be resolved with DNS/hosts file and returns the IP of your server (Or localhost). Since it has to send the host header in the http request to make this work